# PDFBox print list and add new page when needed

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am currently working on a project, where I need to print elements from an `ArrayList` into a PDF file in the following format:

[image: Layout]

The layout above represents one **DIN A4** page that contains of 10 labels with two elements each.

I want to go through my array list that contains all the elements and print them to the labels. How can I force PDFBox to create a new page after 20 labels have been printed onto one page?

Another concern (**more likely looking for ideas here**) is how to get the "jumping" text positioning to work well and dynamic (not hard coded for this one single example layout with 20 elements). I don't want to tell PDFBox to `moveTextPositionByAmount(X,Y)` with fixed `X` and `Y`. I would rather like to let the user enter the amount of labels and label size and let my program do the rest.

Comment: You have chosen PDFBox as PDF library. PDFBox offers only a very low-level API for PDF generation, you essentially hand code (with very thin wrapper methods) the content streams of the pages yourself. Thus, everything that has to do with layout'ing has to be hand-coded by you. (There are some attempts at creating layout'ing libraries on top of PDFBox out there; last time I looked, though, they could probably be used as template for one's own code but not to plug-and-play as is.)

Comment: Okay thank you for this answer I am currently hard coding this as a first attempt to get my application running. Later on I need to redesign this to make all layout dynamic.

Comment: Even though you have to hand-code it, you can do so fairly dynamically, making several values (e.g. number of columns and rows, which elements to print where, ...) variable, governed by externally supplied parameters, etc.

Comment: Yeah this is the way I thought about. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula to get height or width of text based on font size and font type (PDFont):

```
font.getFontDescriptor().getFontBoundingBox().getHeight() / 1000 * fontSize * 0.865
```

In your case, it seems like since you only want to jump to next page after 20 labels you can just keep track of every element you draw and once you reach 20, add a new page and reset your counter back to 0.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Actually I read somewhere that 0.865 was to reduce the error rate. I didn't see that big of a difference but then again, I've paddings on all sides of the pages so I never quite see the difference it may make when you're trying to get the height or width.

Comment: Also, if you want to get the width of a string use: 

 float width = font.getStringWidth(text) / 1000 * fontSize;